# Why $V$ is zero at large time $t$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, capacitance

Here is the original question:

[image: Graph for the question]

In the circuit illustrated above, the point marked $\mathrm{e}_{1}$ is raised instaneously at time $\mathrm{t}_{0}$ from zero to a fixed positive potential. If $\mathrm{e}_{2}$ is connected to a high-impedance D.C. oscilloscope input, the gragh of its voltage $\mathrm{V}$ as a function of time $\mathrm{t}$ will most resemble which of the following?

And here are the two options I am confused about:

[image]

[image]

I think when the circuit is in a stable state, the capacitor is break, then the voltage should all drop on the DC impedance. But I was informed that it's not right since the voltage should drop on the capacitor, i.e. the answer is E.

Why there is no voltage drop on the DC impedance? And why the capacitor will have a voltage drop?

Comment: "Informed" by who?

Answer (score 1):

> Why there is no voltage drop on the DC impedance

If there is a current through the resistor, there will be a voltage drop across it. This is Ohm's law. But now consider this circuit, and how much current flows to the load, and work out for yourself, how  much current will be flowing through the resistor.

> And why the capacitor will have a voltage drop?

The capacitor does have a voltage drop --- there will be different potentials on its two terminals.

But that is not what is shown in answer (E). Answer E would give no voltage drop across the capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an initially uncharged (zero voltage initially across the capacitor) ideal capacitor, the voltage across it cannot change instantaneously. Therefore since the voltage is zero before the step input, it will also be zero immediately after the input.  Both D and E show this. But the capacitor will charge up exponentially until it reaches the input voltage $e_1$ when the current through the resistor is zero.

Given the above, you should be able to figure out which answer is definitely wrong.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The rule for solving circuits with capacitors is that the solution of the circuit by treating the capacitors as open circuits is the one at time infinity.

In this case when you remove the capacitor, and solve the circuit you find all the voltage drop will be on the high impedance oscilloscope input. This is the solution for time=infinity even when the capacitor is back (and thus the voltage drop will be both on the high impedance oscilloscope input and on the capacitor since they are connected in parallel)